# Plugin to email portion of WooCommerce orders to vendors

Tags: wordpress, ecommerce, woocommerce

I have built a WooCommerce store for a client that is a sales rep for about 10-12 wholesale product lines. I have the products set up so that the product categories are the vendors. A customer going to her store could place an order for many items that ultimately will ship from different vendors. So a simple example order might be:

```
Order# 12345
Product A  2 qty (Vendor 1)
Product B  5 qty (Vendor 1)
Product C  6 qty (Vendor 1)
Product D  5 qty (Vendor 2)
Product E 15 qty (Vendor 2)
Product F 25 qty (Vendor 2)
```

I need to give her an easy way to send off one portion of the order to vendor 1 and the other portion of the order to vendor 2. Ideally it would be something like the order confirmation email that gets sent:

[image]

But even if it was an Excel file, that would work. I just need her to be able to select the order# and extract the products by category.

Update: One workaround I was thinking of is to split the orders for shipping purposes, which I've heard you can do. I need to see if I can generate a separate email from that, but it might be a hack that would work.